# Python SOAP clients will not work with this WSDL

Tags: python, soap, soappy, zsi

Thus far I've tried to access this WSDL:

https://login.azoogleads.com/affiliate/tool/soap_api

from the two common Python SOAP clients that I'm aware of: SOAPpy and ZSI.client.Binding.  SOAPpy raises an exception in PyXML (xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)) and ZSI raises an exception in the urlparse library.

What I'm hoping is:

1.) I'm using these libraries incorrectly (usage below)

or

2.) There is another SOAP library I don't know about that will be able to handle this

Here's my usage of the libraries:

```
from ZSI.client import Binding
b = Binding('https://login.azoogleads.com/affiliate/tool/soap_api/')
hash = b.authenticate('should', 'get', 'authenticationfailurefromthis')
```

and

```
import SOAPpy
b = SOAPpy.WSDL.Proxy('https://login.azoogleads.com/affiliate/tool/soap_api/')
hash = b.authenticate('any', 'info', 'shoulddo')
```

Answer (score 2):

your not actually giving it a valid WSDL endpoint try explicilty giving it the WSDL location rather than the directory it is in.  Remember computer are exceptually stupid things!